# Getting per user cpu and memory consumption statistics

Tags: linux, ubuntu, solaris, redhat-enterprise-linux

Is there a way to get cpu and memory consumption statistics summaries per user the same way `prstat -t`  on Solaris shows them?

The prstat(1) utility in Solaris display has fields NPROC UserName SWAP RSS Memory TimeCPU.

Are there any scripts available to generate more or less similar output on a Linux system?

Comment: It gives NPROC UserName SWAP RSS Memory TimeCPU

Comment: Is there any scripts available to generate more or less similar output?

Comment: On production server it is not allowed to install external packages/rpm. Can any one suggest something to be done using script or existing commands on RHEL6 /OEL 6. Thanks.